# Which language to choose for CAD application development

Tags: cad, step

I am planning to develop a CAD application. I am bit confused in deciding which language to chose for the development. My main focus is on the application performance and quality. Right now I have 2 choices QT and VC++.

Which is better from the above 2? Is there any other language which I can use? Any CAD development idea/guide which would help?

Thanks

Comment: Use what you feel most comfortable with.

Comment: QT is a cross platform C++ framework. VC++ likewise is not a language, but a C++ compiler, with a choice of frameworks: .NET, MFC or Win32.

Comment: Good open source CAD you can look at: http://kicad.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to develop a CAD software, you first need a geometric kernel (unless you intend to do it yourself...). Most of them are written in C or C++.

The most known options are either:

1. OpenCascade (FOSS)
2. Parasolid (Proprietary)
3. A direct integration to an existing CAD system (PRO/E, CATIA, SolidWorks, NX, ...)

Once you have a geometric kernel, you can start developing a front-end to your application. QT would be a better option, since it is a well known cross platform framework.

Comment: Hi Gabriel Curvilier , can you suggest which is best kernel to generate NURB surfaces

Answer (score 2):

You could use an open source development framework. [pythonOCC](http://www.pythonocc.org/) provides such a development framework for python. From the website:

> pythonOCC is a 3D CAD/CAE/PLM
>   development framework for the Python
>   programming language. It provides
>   features such as advanced topological
>   and geometrical operations, data
>   exchange (STEP, IGES, STL
>   import/export), 2D and 3D meshing,
>   rigid body simulation, parametric
>   modeling.

PythonOCC is based on the [Open CASCADE](http://www.opencascade.org/), a software development framework developed in C++.

Comment: Hi rochb , can you suggest which is best kernel to generate NURB surfaces